# declares a dependency from configuration 'compileOnly' to configuration 'runtime' which is not declared in the descriptor for

Tags: java, minecraft, gradle-kotlin-dsl, jitpack

My project can be built normally locally, but it cannot be built successfully on jitpack

jitpack build log:https://jitpack.io/com/github/YufiriaMazenta/CrypticLib/3daacc7198/build.log

This is my repository:https://github.com/YufiriaMazenta/CrypticLib

I tried to modify the build method of folia to runtimeOnly, but it failed to compile

I want it to compile successfully on jitpack

build.gradle.kts:

```
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
group = "com.github.yufiriamazenta"
version = "1.0.0-dev11"

plugins {
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven("https://repo.rosewooddev.io/repository/public/")//提供spigot
    maven("https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/")
    maven("https://repo.extendedclip.com/content/repositories/placeholderapi/")
    maven("https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/")
    maven("https://jitpack.io")
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains:annotations:24.0.1")
    compileOnly("net.md-5:bungeecord-chat:1.16-R0.4")
    compileOnly("net.kyori:adventure-api:4.14.0")
    compileOnly("org.spigotmc:spigot:1.20")
    compileOnly("dev.folia:folia-api:1.20.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT") {
        targetConfiguration = "runtime"
    }
    compileOnly("me.clip:placeholderapi:2.11.1")
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile::class.java) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

publishing {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
        from(components["java"])
    }
}
```

complete error message:

```
Build starting...
Start: Fri Aug 11 01:15:29 UTC 2023 a8f97c3ab000
Git:
3daacc7
commit 3daacc71988813cf72411a3e272441b99167434b
Author: ChiyodaXiaoYi 
Date:   Fri Aug 11 09:14:37 2023 +0800

    尝试修复Jitpack构建错误


Init SDKMan
Running before_install command:
sdk install java 17.0.7-oracle;sdk use java 17.0.7-oracle
[1;33mWe periodically need to update the local cache. Please run:[0m

  $ sdk update

[1;36mBroadcasts discontinued. Please follow @sdkman_ on Twitter for announcements.[0m

Downloading: java 17.0.7-oracle

In progress...


###                                                                        4.3%
#######                                                                   10.7%
############                                                              17.1%
################                                                          23.5%
#####################                                                     29.9%
##########################                                                36.3%
##############################                                            42.6%
###################################                                       49.0%
#######################################                                   55.4%
############################################                              61.8%
#################################################                         68.2%
#####################################################                     74.6%
##########################################################                81.0%
##############################################################            87.4%
###################################################################       93.8%
#######################################################################  100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%

Repackaging Java 17.0.7-oracle...

Done repackaging...

[1;32mInstalling: java 17.0.7-oracle[0m
[1;32mDone installing![0m


[1;32mSetting java 17.0.7-oracle as default.[0m
[1;33mWe periodically need to update the local cache. Please run:[0m

  $ sdk update


[1;32mUsing java version 17.0.7-oracle in this shell.[0m
Found gradle
Gradle build script
Found gradle version: 7.3.3.
Using gradle wrapper
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
.10%.20%.30%.40%.50%.60%.70%.80%.90%.100%

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-12-22 12:37:54 UTC
Revision:     6f556c80f945dc54b50e0be633da6c62dbe8dc71

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.7 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.7+8-LTS-224)
OS:           Linux 4.10.0-28-generic amd64

0m3.084s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
java version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224, mixed mode, sharing)
Getting tasks: ./gradlew tasks --all
Tasks: publishToMavenLocal,
Found javadoc task
Running: ./gradlew clean -Pgroup=com.github.YufiriaMazenta -Pversion=3daacc7198 -xtest assemble publishToMavenLocal
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava FAILED
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve dev.folia:folia-api:1.20.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'compileOnly' to configuration 'runtime' which is not declared in the descriptor for dev.folia:folia-api:1.20.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT:20230809.225802-16.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Archive: com.github.yufiriamazenta:CrypticLib:1.0.0-dev11
Publication: com.github.yufiriamazenta:CrypticLib:1.0.0-dev11
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
Found artifact: com.github.yufiriamazenta:CrypticLib:1.0.0-dev11
2023-08-11T01:16:25.837070738Z
Exit code: 0

⚠️ ERROR: No build artifacts found
Expected artifacts in: $HOME/.m2/repository/com/github/yufiriamazenta/CrypticLib/1.0.0-dev11
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.